# Code Complexity Misunderstanding of Single Element in a Sorted Array

Tags: c#, big-o, code-complexity

The problem which is on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-element-in-a-sorted-array/) says that

> You are given a sorted array consisting of only integers where every
> element appears exactly twice, except for one element which appears
> exactly once.
>
> Return the single element that appears only once.
>
> Your solution must run in `O(log n)` time and `O(1)` space.
>
> ```
> Example 1:
>
> Input: nums = [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,8,8]
> Output: 2
> Example 2:
>
> Input: nums = [3,3,7,7,10,11,11]
> Output: 10
> ```

My friend said that leetcode has accepted it as one of its right solution as you can see below image. However, I can't understand how the code is `O(logn)`. Could you explain me? I assert that the code is of `O(n)` because it iterates through one by on up to its size.

[image]

```
public class Solution {
    public int SingleNonDuplicate(int[] nums) {
            int result = nums[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                if (nums[i] != result && i % 2 == 1)
                {
                    result = nums[i - 1];
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = nums[i];
                }
            }

            return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're correct -- that's very much an `O(n)` solution. `O(log n)` in this context needs to be a binary search I think, which is supported by the fact that the input is sorted. Before the single element, `nums[i] == nums[i+1]` for some even `i`, whereas after it, `nums[i] != nums[i+1]`. You need to binary search for the value of `i` at which that change happens

Comment: @canton7 it is too strange that leetcode accepts it! Really awkward. Thank you sir

Comment: How is it going to determine the algorithmic complexity of your submission? It can't analyse it the way a human can: the only thing it can be doing is giving it different-sized inputs to see how long it takes. That isn't particularly accurate. There are a huge number of things which will confound that, as things tend to get faster the longer they run: the JIT does another better-optimized pass; caches warm up; branch prediction gets better, etc. So there's got to be some margin for error there. Presumably this submission just happens to behave sufficiently "log-like" for the inputs being used

Comment: Leetcode won't want to give it *huge* inputs as that will take a long time to process, and they'll need bigger servers, so they'll just be doing the best they can within some restrictions, and the result won't be perfect. If you read the comments for that question there are loads of people submitting linear answers (normally using the classic XOR method for this sort of question)

Comment: @canton7 yes you are right. Thank you for your precious ideas, and comments sir.